# adding custom variables to libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

how do I use Custom variables with libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar? I just added the  new google app tracking library(libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar), any examples. The custom variables class seams to be missing in the new library.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's documentation, Custom Variables are not supported in V2 at this time.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/migration

> Custom variables are not currently supported in version 2, and calls to setCustomVar() should be removed.

Comment: we just have e response from google that the custom variables are not supported, thanks for the answer